# Can't import Gradle project to Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I have a libGDX project that I can compile and run on PC and am trying to get it to run on a mac.  I've been following the setup on https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29

I've checked out my project from my version control and am trying to import it into Eclipse by selecting File/Import..., Gradle Project and then pressing the 'build model' button.  This results in the error

failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.1

I've updated my android project to include the 21 distribution, but am still getting this error.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.1
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.ExceptionUtil.coreException(ExceptionUtil.java:40)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.ExceptionUtil.coreException(ExceptionUtil.java:51)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.BuildResult.get(BuildResult.java:85)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.GradleProjectModelManager.getModelInternal(GradleProjectModelManager.java:145)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.GradleProjectModelManager.getModel(GradleProjectModelManager.java:100)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.GradleModelManager.getModel(GradleModelManager.java:77)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getSkeletalGradleModel(GradleProject.java:669)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.wizards.GradleImportWizardPageOne$11.doit(GradleImportWizardPageOne.java:499)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:104)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of type 'HierarchicalEclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:48)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.ToolinApiUtils.buildModel(ToolinApiUtils.java:103)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.DefaultModelBuilder.doBuild(DefaultModelBuilder.java:30)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.AbstractModelBuilder.buildModel(AbstractModelBuilder.java:40)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.HierarchicalProjectBuildStrategy.buildReferenceModel(HierarchicalProjectBuildStrategy.java:179)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.HierarchicalProjectBuildStrategy.buildModels(HierarchicalProjectBuildStrategy.java:65)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.GradleProjectModelManager.getModelInternal(GradleProjectModelManager.java:141)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.1
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:93)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:90)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.groovy:462)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.access$2(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to edit my android/build.gradle file and change the buildToolsVersion to 21.1.2